# with javascript, how to make string only have letters, numbers, and period. Remove all other characters

Tags: javascript, replace

What to edit in the js below, so this file name: `old_file_name = this8_ file-name=44.jpg`
becomes this:  `new_file_name = this8filename44.jpg`

Replace any character unless it is a letter, number, or .  with ''  (ie. nothing)

```
var old_file_name = file.upload.filename;
new_file_name = old_file_name.replace(/^[ A-Za-z0-9.\s]*$/i, '');
console.log("file name is:"+new_file_name);
console.log("original file name is:"+old_file_name);
```

Comment: What output are you currently getting?

Comment: remove `^` and `$` from your regex - use `[^a-z9-9.]` (the `^` has a different meaning here), add `g` flag - currently your regex matches for the whole value (from ^ beginning to $ end) if it is comprised of A-Za-z0-9 space and white space only

Comment: What your reg exp says: [regexper](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5B%20A-Za-z0-9.%5Cs%5D*%24%2F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply this :

```js
const cleanFileName = fn => fn.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/ig, '')
  ;
let old_file_name = "this8_ file-Name=44.jpg"
  , new_file_name = cleanFileName( old_file_name )
  ;
console.log( old_file_name )  // -> this8_ file-Name=44.jpg
console.log( new_file_name )  // -> this8fileName44.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_file_name = old_file_name.replace(^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$, '');
```

This will check from start to finish if it matched one or more of the conditions.